# Backup batch files to usb flash drive from computer

Tags: file, flash, batch-file, usb, backup

I need to backup batch files from pc to usb flash drive (located in F drive). How do I do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Kindly spend some time by referring to the [help site](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and getting accustomed to the site. For your question, do you mean to copy the batch files or create a batch file to copy the files? If latter, check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811296/copy-a-file-into-usb-flash-drive-root-using-batch-files?rq=1) or other posts on left side under related section.

Comment: By using a batch file containing one line with command __copy__ or __xcopy__ or __robocopy__. Your question with the provided details is answered completely with this comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xcopy command, it has several parameters, for example, you can specify to copy files created after a certain date, or copy folders and subfolders, etc, take a look here: http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

you can backup your files using this script, copy and paste on a plain text file (.txt) modify as needed and replace the extension .txt to .bat, here's the script:

@echo off
echo
xcopy "enter your file path to be copied here, eg C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games and remove quotes, if folder name has spaces, keep quotes" "enter your backup destination here" "enter parameters here, such as /m /d, etc"

so the syntax is:  XCOPY [source] [destination] [options]

here's an example:

`xcopy "C:\Users\Myusername\Documents\My Received Files" E:\Backup /w /E /-Y /V /I`